# how to find, "invalid character ',' looking for beginning of value" error message

Tags: go

I have a short Go program that runs the `go list -json` command for several packages, stores the output of each run of the command in a json.RawMessage, appends each json.RawMessage into a slice of json.RawMessages, and then returns the result to the server after concatenating each of the json.RawMessages together and compacting the json. However, there is an error message that gets produced when I run `json.Compact` that I can't locate the source of. Googling this error message reveals that most people who seem to encounter it--whether it's for an invalid `,` or some other character--have a hard time finding the source of it.

```
invalid character ',' looking for beginning of value
```

The code with comments is available to view here [on play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/ghVvuSYhpg) (although it won't run there) and also below.

Question: can you explain the source of this error and how to prevent it?

(Note, some of the packages were included just for testing purposes)

```
package main

import (
    "expvar"

    "encoding/json"

    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-martini/martini"
    "github.com/zenazn/goji"
    "github.com/zenazn/goji/web"
    "go/build"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
    _ "net/http/pprof"
    "os/exec"
)

type myType struct {
    J []json.RawMessage
}

var pack map[string]string

type GoList struct {
    Imports []string
}

type Import struct {
    Dir        string
    ImportPath string
    Name       string
    Target     string
    Standard   bool
    Root       string
    GoFiles    []string
    Imports    []string
    Deps       []string
}

const contentTypeJSON = "application/json"

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/importgraph", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { importGraph(w, r) })
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Inside handler")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello world from my Go program!")
}

func importGraph(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    pack = make(map[string]string)

    var t myType
    cmd := exec.Command("go", "list", "-json")
    stdout, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {

        println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    var list GoList
    err = json.Unmarshal(stdout, &list)

    for _, d := range list.Imports {
        //get the imports for each of the packages listed by go list -json
        t.imports(d)

    }

    var buff bytes.Buffer

    //concatenate the separate json.RawMessages together into json

    buff.WriteByte('[')

    for i, j := range t.J {

        if i != 0 {
            buff.WriteByte(',')
        }
        buff.Write([]byte(j))
    }
    buff.WriteByte(']')

    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    if err := json.Compact(&buffer, buff.Bytes()); err != nil {
        println(err.Error()) //error message: invalid character ',' looking for beginning of value
        return

    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", contentTypeJSON)

    w.Write(buffer.Bytes())

}

func (myObj *myType) imports(pk string) error {

    cmd := exec.Command("go", "list", "-json", pk)
    stdout, _ := cmd.Output()

    pack[pk] = pk

    var deplist Import
    json.Unmarshal(stdout, &deplist)

    var newj json.RawMessage
    json.Unmarshal(stdout, &newj)
    myObj.J = append(myObj.J, newj)

    for _, imp := range deplist.Imports {

        if _, ok := pack[imp]; !ok {

            myObj.imports(imp) //recursive call to get the imports of the imports etc

        }
    }

    return nil

}
```

Comment: Any more details about the error? Line number/any additional trace?

Comment: @Momer it doesn't give a line number, nor a trace. Is there a way to create a trace?

Comment: @thundercat I wanted the json output of the go list command. Can you suggest how I can turn the out out of go build into json?

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to play with it. Would you recommend that I create some type of struct with embedded slices to hold values as I recurse through the dependency tree? And then convert all to json at end in one go? If so, I'm not sure what the fields on struct would look like

Comment: @ThunderCat thank you go rumour help. can you point out where go list I command is defined? I want yo see how it wraps go build, will try yo use that

Comment: Somewhere you will have `,,` or you might have `,` at end of your json

Comment: I had the same problem, and fixed it using this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60042738/6150881
Hope it helps!

Comment: In my case I fixed it using :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60042738/6150881
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, as has been commented, are you sure you can't use
the `go/build` package directly rather than running `go list`?

I Wouldn't use `println` (or `fmt.Println`) inside HTTP handlers. It's much better to use `log.Println` and/or get the error into the `ResponseWriter`. Also, it's a good idea to wrap your `ListenAndServe` call with `log.Fatal`.

When printing/logging `error` values you can just use `err`, no need to have `err.Error()`.

Further, when you actually want to do something more detailed than just reporting/logging the error message you can look at it's type and other info. For example, `log.Printf("verbose error info: %#v", err)` gives:

```
&json.SyntaxError{msg:"invalid character ',' looking for beginning of value", Offset:0}
```

I tried this because I know the `json` package returns various error types with additional info and I was hoping the offset value would be of help. If it had been then something like this might have been helpful:

```
if err := json.Compact(…) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("json.Compact:", err)
        if serr, ok := err.(*json.SyntaxError); ok {
            log.Println("Occurred at offset:", serr.Offset)
            // … something to show the data in buff around that offset …
        }
    }
}
```

But offset zero isn't helpful :(

So although this doesn't identify you problem hopefully
it can be of some help to your further investigation.

Edit:

So after adding:

```
log.Println("Write file:", ioutil.WriteFile("data.json", buff.Bytes(), 0600))
```

to the above error handling block I then ran a JSON validator on the resultant file and it identified this piece:

```
        "XTestImports": [
                "io",
                "log",
                "net"
        ]
},,{
        "Dir": "/usr/local/go/src/mime",
        "ImportPath": "mime",
        "Name": "mime",
```

Note the double `,,`.

That should tell you whete the error in your code is.
But if not, you need to skip empty entries, either when processing `t.J` or when you build it. The later is better and just involves:

```
    if len(newj) > 0 {
        myObj.J = append(myObj.J, newj)
    }
```

(where btw you don't check for errors from `json.Unmarshal` so it's not clear if that is supposed to ever be empty or if it's empty due to a preceeding error. **Never** ignore error returns!)

Comment: I wanted the json output of go list -json, otherwise I'd have to build json manually and I'm not sure how to do that in go (this is my first go project)

Comment: @Leahcim Investigated a litter further and found the problem. I'll leave the rest of the answer here for you since it should help you realize how you can find this things yourself.

Comment: That's very interesting (how you found the problem) but I'm not entirely sure I understand which characte it's objecting to. Json.Compact was supposed to remove the \n and \t characters, are they the problem? I'll try your cod on my computer

Comment: Ok that error is gone but now I have a new similar  type of error with: invalid character '{'' after array element. Did you get that too?

Comment: @Leahcim start by checking *every* error return from each `json.*` call you're making instead of ignoring them like you do in the `imports` method.

Comment: You removed the part of code from your answer where you 'continue' if the length of t.J is zero, can you please put it back. I think I had copied it incorrectly, hence my subsequent error. Btw, learned a lot from your answer thank you

Answer (score 8):

I also encountered the same error message in a Go program, but the error message was within the HTTP response error, in HTML format when my HTTP response parser expected JSON.

For me, the solution was to change my request to include setting the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`. How you do this depends on which http client library you happen to be using; if you have access to the `http.Header` core type, you can set the header with `.Set(...)`.

I realize the scope of this fix for me may not apply to the original question, but I came here first after googling and thought this would help others, since the message was not particularly obvious at first glance. The hint is that the invalid `<` character is the first HTML character in the error/response, which is likely the result of the request type not being set to `application/json`, thus the server responds with a non JSON response.

Answer (score 8):

I was also facing this error "invalid character 'N' looking for beginning of value".
This error was coming while "unmarshalling the non-json response into a json". I was expecting a json response, so wrote go code to unmarshal it into a json. But, due to URL change, the response that I was getting was a text ie. "404 Not found" error, which cannot be unmarshalled into a json.
"invalid character 'N' looking for beginning of value"

So, to summarise, this error appears when we are trying to unmarshal a non-json response (text/html/xml) into json.

Answer (score 6):

For me the issue was I was trying to parse the already parsed JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Reason for this eerie error message is :

```
// When unmarshaling quoted strings, invalid UTF-8 or
// invalid UTF-16 surrogate pairs are not treated as an error.
// Instead, they are replaced by the Unicode replacement
// character U+FFFD.
```

https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/decode.go

In my case I saved my json as string then parsed it by :
`stringData = JSON.parse(myJsonString)`

I also had the same error another time using gin-context-ShouldBind() (https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.ShouldBind) and mapping my json to go object:
error was because it needs a json as string, so I used : JSON.stringify(jsonObject) when sending my request from front-end part.

Answer (score 1):

And in case someone has the same problem as me, I needed to call JSON.stringify on my post data.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem with my error message being:

> invalid character 'I' looking for beginning of value

In my case, i was trying to decode `BSON` using `json.Unmarshal`. Json doesn't recognize the `ISODate` type, which caused this error.

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay I resolved it by expecting BSON instead of JSON and using bson.Unmarshal instead of json.Unmarshal. Once i debugged the byte array it made sense json was not able to parse because in it was something like {"date": ISODate("2010-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")}

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. For me I omitted the first letter of my authorization token. So instead of

```
"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InJhcGhhZWxuZ0BlbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE2MTM5NTQzMjB9.yPGC937VNAF8Qg05Z1x3fZ3zu_MUs-cA_Iag5-4RcJE"
```

I used this

```
"yJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InJhcGhhZWxuZ0BlbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE2MTM5NTQzMjB9.yPGC937VNAF8Qg05Z1x3fZ3zu_MUs-cA_Iag5-4RcJE"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [hashicorp/setup-terraform](https://github.com/hashicorp/setup-terraform) GitHub Action, you'll need to ensure the wrapper is disabled so the terraform binary is installed normally.

e.g.

- uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
  with:
  terraform_wrapper: false