# Golang invalid character 'b' looking for beginning of value

Tags: json, xml, go

I am trying to post json with a xml message inside it. However it returns:

```
invalid character 'b' looking for beginning of value
```

I think the possible reason is that I am trying to marshal the returns body which is not in the json format.

```
func (s *BackendConfiguration) Do(req *http.Request, v interface{}) error {
    log.Printf("Requesting %v %v%v\n", req.Method, req.URL.Host, req.URL.Path)
    start := time.Now()

    res, err := s.HTTPClient.Do(req)

    if debug {
        log.Printf("Completed in %v\n", time.Since(start))
    }

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Request to sakura failed: %v\n", err)
        return err
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    resBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Cannot parse sakura response: %v\n", err)
        return err
    }

    if debug {
        log.Printf("sakura response: %q\n", resBody)
    }

    if v != nil {
        return json.Unmarshal(resBody, v)
    }

    return nil
}
```

The error happened at this line:

```
return json.Unmarshal(resBody, v)
```

Comment: `{{` isn't valid json, but that doesn't correlate with the invalid `b` either. Please make a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're having.

Comment: Don't just show the error. Show which line is giving you the error and what is the req in that scenario.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The error indicates that the server did not return a valid JSON response.  I suggest adding the following code to debug the issue:

```
err := json.Unmarshal(resBody, v)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("error decoding sakura response: %v", err)
    if e, ok := err.(*json.SyntaxError); ok {
        log.Printf("syntax error at byte offset %d", e.Offset)
    }
    log.Printf("sakura response: %q", resBody)
    return err
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Reason for this eerie error message is :

```
// When unmarshaling quoted strings, invalid UTF-8 or
// invalid UTF-16 surrogate pairs are not treated as an error.
// Instead, they are replaced by the Unicode replacement
// character U+FFFD.
```

https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/decode.go

In my case I saved my json as string then parsed it by :
`stringData = JSON.parse(myJsonString)`

I also had the same error another time using gin-context-ShouldBind() (https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.ShouldBind) and mapping my json to go object:
error was because it needs a json as string, so I used : JSON.stringify(jsonObject) when sending my request from front-end part.

Answer (score 2):

Please Check the request header first. Check the Content-Type. In my cases, it's not an `application/JSON`. It's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded.`

Answer (score 1):

I have the problem, too. It's because vue request api stringifies the json data, keep request data is json data.
like `curl apiUrl -H '' -d '{"a":1,"b":2}'`,
not `curl apiUrl -H '' -d 'a=1&b=2'`,
I think keep your response is json data will be resolved

Answer (score 1):

Use this option, `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`, while making a POST request.
 Also use the bash shell rather than cmd or powershell for a POST request. The command shell doesnt support single quotes. You need to escape the double quotes with \ inside the json content for cmd.

Comment: It saved me a lot of time, I have to use "\" to escape all the double quotes in the POST. This is a successful curl statement that I used under MS Windows Powershell:                                           curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -X POST -d '{\"username\":\"david\", \"password\":\"hero\"}' http://localhost:8000/auth/register

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. My mistake was very specific to what I was doing. I was formatting my string, but didn't put the quotes for the substituted variables.

The body I was putting in was this

```
respBody := fmt.Sprintf(`{"a": %s, "b": %s}`, "a", "b")
```

This was formatted to

```
{"a": a, "b": b}
```

I didn't realize I needed to add the quotes. It needs to be like

```
respBody := fmt.Sprintf(`{"a": "%s", "b": "%s"}`, "a", "b")
```

This was formatted to

```
{"a": "a", "b": "b"}
```

The offset was referring to the first char of the unquoted string.