# invalid character 'R' looking for beginning of value

Tags: go, url-parsing

I am trying to hit a url

```
http://localhost:33250/api/v1/edit-order-request/?order_id=1231
```

, there I get this error :

```
invalid character 'R' looking for beginning of value
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit :
http_client.go

```
func (c *HTTPClient) Call(url string, body interface{}, h http.Header, hc string, method string) (*response.BaseResponse, error) {
    outputChannel := make(chan *response.BaseResponse, 1)
    util.FilterHeaders(&h)
    errChannel := hystrix.Go(hc, func() error {
        var res *http.Response
        var err error
        switch method {

        case util.Post:
            rbyte, _ := json.Marshal(body)
            rreader := bytes.NewReader(rbyte)
            res, err = c.httpClient.Post(url, rreader, h)
        case util.Put:
            rbyte, _ := json.Marshal(body)
            rreader := bytes.NewReader(rbyte)
            res, err = c.httpClient.Put(url, rreader, h)
        case util.Patch:
            rbyte, _ := json.Marshal(body)
            rreader := bytes.NewReader(rbyte)
            res, err = c.httpClient.Patch(url, rreader, h)
        case util.Get:
            res, err = c.httpClient.Get(url, h)
            log.Info().Msgf("res %v",res)
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Error().Err(err).Msgf(method+" api failed: %s", body)
            return err
        }
        defer res.Body.Close()
        var baseResponse response.BaseResponse
        d := json.NewDecoder(res.Body)
        d.UseNumber()
        err = d.Decode(&baseResponse)
        if err != nil {
            log.Error().Err(err).Msgf("Failed to decode the response for url %s", url)
            return err
        }
        baseResponse.HTTPStatusCode = res.StatusCode

        outputChannel <- &baseResponse
        return nil
    }, func(err error) error {
        return err
    })
    select {
    case res := <-outputChannel:
        log.Info().Msgf(method+" response for URL %s, BODY %s , HEADER %s, RESPONSE %s", url, util.ToJSON(body), util.ToJSON(h), util.ToJSON(res))
        return res, nil
    case err := <-errChannel:
        log.Info().Msgf("Error received on error channel for URL %s", url)
        return nil, err
    }
}
```

Stub :

```
var EditServiceGetConversationIdOmtTaskIdNonEmptyStub = &wiremock.Stub{
    Request: wiremock.Request{
        Method:     "GET",
        UrlPattern: "/api/v1/edit-order-request/"+"?order_id=1231",
    },
    Response: wiremock.Response{
        Status: 200,
        Body:   EditServiceGetConversationIdOmtTaskIdNonEmptyResponse,
    },
}

var EditServiceGetConversationIdOmtTaskIdNonEmptyResponse = "{\"statusCode\":0,\"statusMessage\":\"success\",\"data\":{\"order_id\":1231,\"edit_reason\":\"EDIT\",\"crm_conversation_id\":\"p-qwr-1234\",\"omt_task_id\":\"1231\"}}"
```

When in stub I use Url parameter , then this error is gone. Could someone explain me the reason for this  ?

Error Logs when using Url Pattern as parameter :

```
http_client.go:54 > res &{404 Not Found 404 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Type:[text/plain] Server:[Jetty(9.4.20.v20190813)]] 0xc001fd5200 -1 [] true false map[] 0xc0003e6100 <nil>}
http_client.go:66 > Failed to decode the response for url http://localhost:33350/api/v1/edit-order-request/?order_id=1231 error="invalid character 'R' looking for beginning of value"
http_client.go:81 > Error received on error channel for URL http://localhost:33350/api/v1/edit-order-request/?order_id=1231
```

Success Logs in case of Url as Parameter :

```
http_client.go:54 > res &{200 OK 200 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Matched-Stub-Id:[901cbfb1-fc1a-40e8-9f00-fae29f54be3d] Server:[Jetty(9.4.20.v20190813)] Vary:[Accept-Encoding, User-Agent]] 0xc0020aa8a0 -1 [] true true map[] 0xc0020a0600 <nil>}
http_client.go:78 > GET response for URL http://localhost:33355/api/v1/edit-order-request/?order_id=1231, BODY null , HEADER {"Authorization":["Basic R0dZU1dJOjIwMTVTVyFHR1k="],"Content-Type":["application/json"]}, RESPONSE {"statusCode":0,"statusMessage":"success","data":{"crm_conversation_id":"p-qwr-1234","edit_reason":"EDIT","omt_task_id":"1231","order_id":1231},"httpStatusCode":200,"id":0,"code":"","message":""}
```

Comment: [The URL is valid](https://play.golang.org/p/27ndashDSbP).  The problem is in code that we cannot see.  Edit the question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Actually I am wiremocking this url. Then I start functional test this error shows up, but when I remove the ? symbol, then it works fine.

Comment: I agree with Muffin Top that we cannot help you unless you post the client code which results in this error. However, your error is the same one as in this question so maybe the answers may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943089/golang-invalid-character-b-looking-for-beginning-of-value